# How to use a value from a textbox with OnChange in a new function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onchange

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. I am getting a value from PHP and putting it in a textbox (function 1). That works fine.
2. I am trying to use that value in another PHP query (function 2). Does not work fine.

Both functions should start on loading the page and must remain in separate functions. Problem: the result variable of the first function cannot be found in the second one. As I tried to point out inside the code, the variable "seizoen" remains empty in the second function. Any idea what I am doing wrong here or how I can solve this?

```
<input type="text" id="Seizoen_text" OnChange="getCompetitie()>

<select id="Competitie_list"></select>

window.onload = function() {
    getSeizoen();    
    getCompetitie();
};

function getSeizoen() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'get_seizoen.inc.php',
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(response){
            var maxseizoen = response[0]['MaxSeizoen'];
            $("#Seizoen_text").val(maxseizoen);
        }
    });
}

function getCompetitie() {
    seizoen = $("#Seizoen_text").val();
    alert(seizoen);  //  **--> EMPTY !**
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'get_competitie.inc.php',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: {seizoen: seizoen},
        success: function(response){
            $("#Competitie_list").empty();
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                var competitievorm = response[i]['Competitie'];
                $("#Competitie_list").append("<option value='"+competitievorm+"'>"+competitievorm+"</option>");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That could be it. I thought referencing it in the second function was enough. Any suggestions what I should do here exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the asynchronous calls.

What's happening is `getSeizoen()` gets called on window load, but it does an ajax call. While the ajax call executes on the server, during this time `getCompetitie()` is also called.

In `getCompetitie()` you are populating the variable `seizoen = $("#Seizoen_text").val();` but the textbox probably doesn't have the value yet (since its an asynchronous call).

I'd suggest removing the call to `getCompetitie()` from the `window.load` event and call it once the first ajax has completed. There are multiple ways to do this but you could do something like:

```
function getSeizoen()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'get_seizoen.inc.php',
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(response){
            var maxseizoen = response[0]['MaxSeizoen'];
            $("#Seizoen_text").val(maxseizoen);
            getCompetitie(); // added call here on success
        }
    });
}
```